# How do you delete user accounts in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

The only way I have found to delete user accounts in meteor (other than emptying the database with mrt reset), is by actually logging into that specific user account, and deleting the account from the console, using:

```
Meteor.users.remove('the user id');
```

But like I said, I need to be logged in as that specific user, and have not been able to find a solution which enables me to delete any user from the db.  I'm sure it has something to do with permissions or roles, but I am not sure how to proceed / what is the best solution / how to set an administrative role for a particular user, so that I can delete different user accounts.

Comment: You do not need to be logged, as long as you explicitly the right to delete a user on the server side: Meteor.users.Users.allow({remove: function (){ return true;}}); Obviously you should return true only when you trust this call / the user…

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could do

`meteor mongo`

or

`meteor mongo myapp.meteor.com` for a deployed app

Then

`db.users.remove({_id:<user id>});`

I wouldn't recommend it but if you want to delete any user without being logged in from meteor you would need to modify the allow rules. But deleting a user is a very unlikely event hence the above might be the best way to do it.

Anyway if you do want, modify the `Meteor.users.allow({remove:function() { return true });` property. See http://docs.meteor.com/#allow. You could add in some custom logic there so it'll only let you do so if you're the admin

Comment: @EricLeroy I think they expect you to know a bit about mongodb, just like knowing javascript and handlebars is a given.

Comment: @booyaa, yes, I realized that, but when I pulled up mongo, it did not include my mongo database for meteor.  The key was using meteor mongo

Answer (score 10):

I was having trouble doing this on nitrous.io because I couldn't open both Meteor and Mongo. I put:

```
Meteor.users.remove(' the _id of the user ');
```

in the isServer section to remove the user.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is still looking for an answer to this question, I have outlined my solution below.

When I create a new user, I add a field called role in my user document. If I want a user to be able to remove other users from the `Meteor.users` collection, I give him a role of `administrator`. If not, I give him a role of `member`. So, my user document looks something like this -

```
{
  "_id" : ...,
  "createdAt" : ...,
  "services" : {...},
  "username" : "test",
  "profile" : {
    "name" : "Test Name",
    "role" : "administrator"
  }
}
```

On the client, I have a list of users (added using a `#each` template tag) with a remove button next to each user. A user has to login to see this list. I defined an event handler for the remove button -

```
'click #remove-user-btn': function () {
  Meteor.users.remove({ _id: this._id }, function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Error removing user: ", error);
    } else {
      console.log("Number of users removed: " + result);
    }
  })
}
```

However, Meteor.users does not allow remove operations from the client by default. So, you have to edit the `Meteor.users.allow` callback in the server as shown below to allow the users to be removed from the client side. But we need to make sure that only a user with an administrator role is allowed this privilege.

```
Meteor.users.allow({
  remove: function (userId, doc) {
    var currentUser, userRole;
    currentUser = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: userId }, { fields: { 'profile.role': 1 } });
    userRole = currentUser.profile && currentUser.profile.role;
    if (userRole === "administrator" && userId !== doc._id) {
      console.log("Access granted. You are an administrator and you are not trying to delete your own document.");
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log("Access denied. You are not an administrator or you are trying to delete your own document.");
      return false;
    }
  },
  fetch: []
});
```

This is the general idea. You can build upon this to suit your needs.

Comment: Don't put important info like that in the `user.profile` object unless you *really* know what you're doing! That object is editable from the client even after `insecure` has been removed(!) It's better to put the `role` field on the root user document, or under some other custom field. https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes#profile-editing

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to delete user from mongo through console:
step 1: open new console
step 2: change diretory to your app such as (cd myapp)
step 3 : enter command **meteor mongo**
step 4: make sure there exists a table called users, `db.users.find({});`
step 5: find the userid of the user you wish to delete and type :

```
db.users.remove({_id:"nRXJCC9wTx5x6wSP2"}); // id should be within quotes
```